# How to create individual Objects out of Object with applied Array Modifier?

Tags: modifiers

When I watched some tutorial videos, they often use outdated commands.

Most of the time I can find the ones for the current version on the internet but I have not been able to find the command for turning an array into individual objects.

Comment: Your question would be clearer with a Blender screen capture.  Please include a screen capture in this and all future requests.  You wrote [ I am starting to use blender ], so this advice is especially true according to what you wrote.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "current" version? Since Blender 2.80 is still in Beta, 2.79 is the current version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just click on the Apply button in the Array Modifier panel. If that gives you all the meshes as a single object, which it seems to, then go into edit mode, Select All, then press P to separate all loose parts into separate objects.